# Why I cannot access values in my object after navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() assigning values to it and returns it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigator, react-google-maps

When I assign values to my pos object in function whereAmI using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() I can see than lat and lng are inside the object, however when I am trying to use those properties, they return undefined. Many thanks for any help!

```
import React, {useEffect, useState }  from 'react';

import { GoogleMap } from "react-google-maps"


import './Map.css';

function Map({mapsData}) {

  const myLocation = whereAmI();

  console.log(myLocation); // this returns object with values

  return (
      <GoogleMap 
      defaultZoom={12} 
      defaultCenter={{myLocation}}
      >
      { /* We will render our data here */ }
      </GoogleMap>
  )
}

export default Map;


// helper function to get my current location 
function whereAmI() {
  let pos = {};
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position)=> {
    pos.lat = position.coords.latitude;
    pos.lng = position.coords.longitude;
  })
  console.log(pos); // this returns an object as well with properties but pos.lat or pos.lng returns undefined
  return pos;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentLocation()` is an asynchronous function, so your console.log statement and your return statement are executing before pos.lat and pos.lng have been defined. That is why getCurrentLocation accepts a callback function that executes upon successfully returning the location.